# Reading gallery folders using Implicit intent

Tags: android, android-intent, photo, android-implicit-intent

I am implementing an android app, which will synchronize images from selected folder to server (as Google Photo). I want that user will select folder by clicking on button. I can achieve this by creating my own view. But, if implicit intent can  any implicit intent action by which I can show user only images folder from device?

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

change **EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI** constant accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Rohit, But it will return us image path, we want folder path